# ListView using fragment

Tags: listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am following the Google's nano degree and completed first lesson of the weather app. The app uses a fragment which i have created while creating project. The video shows a "placeholderfragment" class with a "oncreateview" method in main_Activity.java file where the code is written. But in my Android studio, there is no class of such form in main_Activity.java. Instead, there is another file with name mainActivityFragment. Also in the xml files there is an extra file with name content_scrolling.xml which contains the fragment tag pointing to the fragment xml file. I used some of these files and did everything necessary. The app runs but there is no list is showing up. The app has a tool bar with app name and a white screen.

Checkout the code.

Main_Activity.xml in Blankapp with ftagment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />
<!--
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />--></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content_scrolling.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.udacity_test.vatsan.udacity_test.MainActivityFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

List_item_forecast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
   ></TextView>
```

Fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.udacity_test.vatsan.udacity_test.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

</FrameLayout>
```

Main_Activity.java

```
package com.udacity_test.vatsan.udacity_test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MainActivityFragment.java

```
package com.udacity_test.vatsan.udacity_test;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String tmp[]= {
                "Sunday-", "monday", "tueday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"
        };
        ArrayList<String> fake_data= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tmp));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapt= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forcast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,fake_data);
        ListView mylistview= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_listview);
        mylistview.setAdapter(adapt);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mainActivityFragment java file, in onCreateView method you have inflated the layout to the variable "rootview". Since you have identified the listview using rootview, you must return this rootview instead of returning a new inflated view of the layout file.

Replace this line

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

With

```
return rootview;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks man works perfectly. rootView was assigned with inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);. So basically both are same. Then why didn't i get the us?

Comment: Glad it helped. To answer your question, well both the statements are not the same. rootView contains a listview to which has some data binded to it using an adapter. Whereas   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false); returns a view with a listview which has no data in it. This is the reason why you were seeing an empty listview on the screen

Comment: Well I am stuck at another place. After connecting to the open weather api, the app stops as predicted in the udacity video training. Actually i have to get a networkOnMain exception. But i have the network code in the separate fragment file instead of placeholderfragment(). I am getting a Nullpointer exception and a inflate exception.